# Alternative to SQL Tools and Toad IDEs for Oracle query development

Tags: oracle, toad, sqltools

Are there any better alternatives to using SQL Tools and TOAD for writing stored procs and queries for Oracle DB?

Better in the sense of being able to debugg large queries and stored procedures.

Any pointers are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our company uses [PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.nl/plsqldev.html). I am not familiar with SQL Tools or TOAD, but this tool has worked rather well for us with regards to debugging.

Comment: Yep... (+1)
PL/SQL developer rocks.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html)